# They praise her more than do him

Tags: comparative

**(1)** *They praise her more than him*. — correct but ambiguous because can mean both (2) and (3)

**(2)** *They praise her more than he praises her*. — correct
**(2a)** *They praise her more than he does*. — correct
I think (2) = (2a).

**(3)** *They praise her more than they praise him*. — correct
**(3a)** *They praise her more than praise him*. — **is it correct?**
**(3b)** *They praise her more than they do him*. — **is it correct?**
**(3c)** *They praise her more than do him*. — **is it correct?**
I think (3) = (3a) = (3b) = (3c).

Could you tell me please whether (3a), (3b) & (3c) are correct?

Comment: (2a) is more natural than (2).  (3a) and (3c) are not correct.

Comment: @KateBunting From your post I infer that (3) & (3b) are correct. And by analogy with (2) & (2a), we can also say (3b) is more natural than (3). Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii actually not, (3) is in fact more natural than (3b). "than they do him" is a fairly formal construction and doesn't usually sound natural.

Comment: #1 is ***not*** ambiguous! It can only mean #3, never #2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misunderstanding

Comment: On balance, this question looks like a pointless exercise involving a few random rearrangements just to see which if any are still syntactically valid. It's not meaningfully querying some aspect of syntax that the OP needs help understanding.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I find I disagree with your three recent comments. I find #1 somewhat ambiguous as I say in my revised answer; I do not agree that this question is pointless; nor that it should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that 3A and 3B are both grammatically valid, although 3A is unusual and would probably not be said by a fluent or native speaker.

However, I think 3C is grammatically wrong, one simply cannot use "*do*" in that way. Such a use of "do" requires a subject, as in (3B).

> (1) They praise her more than him.

Could in my view mean either of:

> - (2) They praise her more than he praises her.
> - (3) They praise her more than they praise him.

although it is more likely to mean #3, unless wider context indicates otherwise. In this I disagree with  user FumbleFingers.

> (2B) They praise her more than he praises.

is in my view significantly more awkward, and less natural than

> (2) They praise her more than he praises her.

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me one more thing: "_They praise her more than he does/praises_." - as far as I understand, although it's more natural with "_does_" but it's also natural with "_praises_". Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: "They praise her more than him" is perfect and unambiguous. "Him" can't function as a subject. To say it could mean "They praise her more than he praises her" implies that "Him praises her" is correct. "They praise her more than **he**", which is rather old-fashioned, is a grammatically correct way to say "...more than he does".